# indicator-stickynotes 404 error

Tags: 12.04, stickynotes

I am using ubuntu 12.04 I tried to install indicator-sticky notes using the ppa as mentioned

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
```

but it doesn't installs instead it gives a 404 error for the ppa. Is the link not valid now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternatively download tar.gz file from [here](http://launchpad.net/indicator-stickynotes)
(There is no command line option for 12.10- Are you sure you are using 12.04)

I have tried just now for 13.04, it is fetching and works. 404 error may be temporary.

Comment: Ya. I'm using 12.04 on my virtual box and always gives this error. Thanks.